# Installing tensorflow through docker on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: image, docker, ubuntu-14.04, tensorflow, jupyter

I've tried to install tensorflow on Ubuntu 14.04 through docker. It has been added to the docker images successfully. But when I run the docker image, I get the following error.

```
[I 16:12:44.450 NotebookApp] Writing notebook server cookie secret to /root/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/notebook_cookie_secret
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/widgetsnbextension/__init__.py:30: UserWarning: To use the jupyter-js-widgets nbextension, you'll need to update
the Jupyter notebook to version 4.2 or later.
the Jupyter notebook to version 4.2 or later.""")
[W 16:12:44.479 NotebookApp] WARNING: The notebook server is listening on all IP addresses and not using encryption. This is not recommended.
[W 16:12:44.479 NotebookApp] WARNING: The notebook server is listening on all IP addresses and not using authentication. This is highly insecure and not recommended.
[I 16:12:44.486 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /notebooks
[I 16:12:44.486 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels 
[I 16:12:44.486 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at: http://[all ip addresses on your system]:8888/
[I 16:12:44.486 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
```

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: What issue? seems that the image is running fine.  those warnings apply if you are not running docker

Comment: @fabrizioM The warnings appear and it prevents docker from opening its console. I have installed a 'caffe' image. when I execute `docker run -it caffe_image_id` it enters the console as `root@1879d69eb104:/workspace#`. But I can't do the same thing with 'tensorflow'. Maybe because of the warnings.

Comment: I found the answer. when executing the docker image it should be `docker run -it gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow /bin/bash`  Then it enters the interactive console

Comment: now I understand the issue :) glad you found the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When executing the docker image it should be

`docker run -it gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow /bin/bash`

Then it enters the interactive console